# Connect from Macbook Air 2012 (thunderbolt port) to dell monitor (displayport)

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

I just bought this Dell UltraSharp U2312HM monitor to use as an external monitor of my Macbook Air 2012 model.

And, I'm looking for a cable that will connect from thunderbolt port (mini displayport) to displayport of the monitor and wanted to confirm
if this cable is the right one.

[Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort Cable M-M 2m](http://www.extremepc.co.nz/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=464_467&products_id=8839&zenid=958981821e5a140f3d2d8952a6de3c54)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct. If you want some other examples, then take a look at the [newegg site](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=mini%20displayport%20to%20displayport&N=-1&isNodeId=1).